# How do I access data from 3taps API in C#?

Tags: api, programming

I know this sounds more like a developer question, and more suitable for StackOverflow, but I'm hoping for a more theoretical answer because I'm completely new to APIs.

I'm trying to develop an Android application with Xamarin Studio. What I would like to do is display some data via an existing API (3taps) on the application's interface. It sounds pretty simple, but I have looked for C# / .NET tutorials all day and I can't find anything that doesn't start with creating the API first.

Can somebody please tell me what steps I need to take in order to do this? You can assume I know nothing about APIs, other than they allow you to access data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest learning about what an API is from ['An Introduction to APIs' by Zapier](https://zapier.com/learn/apis/) and then some more specific information about consuming JSON APIs w/ .NET from ['Making JSON Web APIs with ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta and ASP.NET Web API'](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

[Unirest](http://unirest.io/net.html) is a simple HTTP request client to look into as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ Mark Silverberg. I'm looking into Unirest right now. It seems to work for this API on Mashape, but I don't know if the library is compatible with Xamarin. I don't see it as a NuGet package.

Comment: @Learnin2Code I am seeing Unirest on nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unirest-API/1.0.5.5-beta . Unirest is compatible with any HTTP request based API, not just Mashape APIs. See https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-net for more details.

Comment: Thanks again Mark. Sorry, this is all new to me. It appears that I need to use the Package Manager Console to install this package, but Xamarin Studio does not currently have a Package Manager Console.

Comment: Oh wait I figured it out. I didn't have "include prereleased versions" checked. Awesome thank you